# I need help on UIScrollView and when tapping on it to do something

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I made a ScrollView and I put a UIButton on the ScrollView so I can go back on the Initial ViewController. But I want it so when I go on the UIScrollView and tap on the screen ,my button will popup from the top. I don't want it to be a SwipeGesture: I just want that when I tap it down, it will popup.

I'm using Xcode Swift

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bind UIPanGestureRecognizer with a selector that has:
`animateWithDuration(delay:, options:, animations:, completion:)`
to visual/hide/move your button.